# SetCursor: Cursor does not contain a definition for "SetCursor' or why can't I re-assign the cursor in Unity 20194.7f?

Tags: unity, mouse, settings

Here is the code I used on Cursor script, attached to a chest object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cursor : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Texture2D cursorArrow;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Cursor.visible = false;

        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorArrow, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
    }

}
```

For some reason, I can no longer reset cursor properties and I don't know why. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You named your MonoBehaviour class "`Cursor`" so when you write the word "`Cursor`" inside the body of that class, the compiler thinks you're trying to refer to your MonoBehaviour (which has a method called `Start`, and no method called `SetCursor`)

Solution: name your class something that does not collide with other types you want to use, like `public class CustomCursor : MonoBehaviour ...`